# Regex matching in rejex101.com but not in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing this regex: https://regex101.com/r/jB1cO7/1

I'm trying to capture everything between the pointy brackets, and it seems to match what I want in regex101.

When I try to do this in node.js:

```
var regex = /<(.+?\.?.+?)>|<(.*)>/g;    
var specialStrings = regex.exec(message);
console.log('special strings are ',specialStrings);
```

I get:

```
[ '<Users.username.53a47a469c52c9d83a2d71d9>',
'Users.username.53a47a469c52c9d83a2d71d9',
undefined,
index: 0,
input: 'message is  <Users.username.53a47a469c52c9d83a2d71d9> has published a new Announcement in Test. Click <hyperlink> to watch the 1slide announcement' ]
```

So why does it match on regex101, but not in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access all matches and capture groups you need to iterate over the matches with exec:

```
var message = "message is  <Users.username.53a47a469c52c9d83a2d71d9> has published a new Announcement in CommercialTribe. Click <hyperlink> to watch the 1slide annonucement";

var regex = /<(.+?\.?.+?)>|<(.*)>/g;    
//var regex = /<.*>/g;
var myMatch = regex.exec(message);

while (myMatch != null){
    console.log(myMatch);
    myMatch = regex.exec(message);
}
```

groups will be available on "myMatch[1]" and "myMatch[2]"

Answer (score 1):

Why not using this regex: `/<(.*?)>/g`?

Comment: Great, I'll use that instead. That doesn't fix the problem though

Answer (score 1):

```
specialStrings = message.match(regex);
```

Allows you to capture multiple groups. `exec` will stop at the first one I believe.

Comment: Oh. That explains a lot if it stops at the first one.

Answer (score 0):

A call to `str.match(re)` will give you all the matches.

```
var str = "message is  <Users.username.53a47a469c52c9d83a2d71d9> has published a new Announcement in Test. Click <hyperlink> to watch the 1slide announcement";

var re = /<[^>]+?>/g;

str.match(re);    
// ["<Users.username.53a47a469c52c9d83a2d71d9>", "<hyperlink>"]
```

Or you can keep calling `re.exec(str)` until you get a `null` answer back

```
var str = "message is  <Users.username.53a47a469c52c9d83a2d71d9> has published a new Announcement in Test. Click <hyperlink> to watch the 1slide announcement";

var re = /<([^>]+?)>/g;

re.exec(str);
// ["<Users.username.53a47a469c52c9d83a2d71d9>", "Users.username.53a47a469c52c9d83a2d71d9"]

re.exec(str);
// ["<hyperlink>", "hyperlink"]

re.exec(str);
// null
```